# 19.10 - Reset system policies

Tags: 19.10, policy

Is there a way to reset all the system policies to their factory defaults without reinstalling ubuntu?

In fact, my problem is that it asks for my password literally for everything I try to do, even for wifi scans. It also asks for my passwords like ~15 times when I log in for something related to *color profiles*.

BTW I'm logged in as a sudo user (admin).

I don't know if it matters but I just got out of a login loop by reinstalling ligthdm. It wasn't doing this before.

[image: authentication requred]

Comment: What do you mean by "*I'm logged in as a sudo user*"?    A login loop can be you're out of space in $HOME (was it a gui login, have you made changes to video/X/etc which could also be a cause..)

Comment: In fact, I was stuck at the login screen (gui) but I managed to fix it by reinstalling gdm3 and lightdm and then switch from gdm3 to lightdm. That's all I did. I didn't touch /video/X/etc

By sudo I mean a user in the sudo group not the root user

Answer (score -1):

Do you have chrome-remote-desktop installed?

I had the same problem, and uninstalling chrome-remote-desktop was the fix, as per [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227842/ubuntu-18-04-gnome-settings-how-to-fix-system-policy-prevents-changes-contact)